# How Send form data to api with amp Nextjs via axios

Tags: reactjs, next.js, amp-html

In my next amp project, I have a regular  when I hit submit it sends the right data but it doesn't set the authentication headers on the request. I have Axios configured to attach these headers on every request so I need to send the data via Axios:

```
footer_submitForm = (e) => {

    e.preventDefault();
    var country = this.country;
    var lobs = this.lobs;
    var voucher_name = this.voucher_name;
    var lead_url = this.lead_url;
    var utm_source = this.utm_source;
    var utm_medium = this.utm_medium;
    var utm_campaign = this.utm_campaign;
    var selectcity = this.state.hero_cityName.value;
    var c_city = this.current_city.value;

    axios.get(`https://www.example.com/api/sendvoucher?email=${this.state.hero_Email}&mobile_number=${this.state.hero_Cellphone}&contact_person=${this.state.hero_Name}&country=${this.country.value}&city=${this.state.hero_cityName.value}&brand=${this.state.brandName}&vouncher_name=${this.voucher_name.value}&utm_source=${this.utm_source.value}&utm_medium=${this.utm_medium.value}&utm_campaign=${this.utm_campaign.value}&lobs=${this.lobs.value}&lead_url=${this.lead_url.value}`, {})

        .then(res => {


            this.setState({ hero_Cellphone: "" });
            this.setState({ hero_Email: "" });
            this.setState({ hero_Name: "" });

            this.setState({ showSuccessModal: true });

        })
        .catch(error => { // your error handling goes here}
            this.setState({ showErrorModal: true });
        });

};
```

form start here....

```
                <input value={this.state.hero_Cellphone} onChange={this.hero_Cellphone} type="tel" placeholder="Cellphone" name="hero_Cellphone" maxLength="10" />
                <br />
                <input value={this.state.hero_Email} onChange={this.hero_Email} type="email" name="email" id="email1" placeholder="Email ID" />
                <br />

                <button type="button" onClick={this.footer_submitForm} name="submit">SEND</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't call API on the AMP page with Axios, You can send form data with the `amp-form` component with some limitations. (you can't send files in amp-form)